# How Can I Give Mathematical Reason For Discrepancies Between Theoretical and Experimental Probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For an experiment where a trial can be conducted with a theoretical probability for each outcome, is it enough to say that the discrepancies between theoretical and experimental probabilities can be explained away as the number of trials I complete increases, it will lead to the experimental probability getting closer to theoretical probability?

For example, the theoretical probability of rolling a 6 when a fair die is rolled is 1/6. However, I could roll a die 10 times and only get six once, which is 1/10. Is it possible to say that:

If $n$ is the number of trials conducted, as $n$ approaches infinity, will the experimental probability approach the theoretical probability? Are there any other ways to explain the discrepancies? Assuming that all theoretical probability calculations are correct.

Comment: Basically, it is as you mentioned in the last part of the question. Note that $10$ dice throws cannot give the expected number of sixes at all.

Comment: Maybe the die is not fair?

Comment: Could be interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

Comment: Well, a *well designed* experiment *always* trumps theoretical results if the discrepancy is "large".  However, first you need some measure of how well your experimental trials aligned with theoretical trials, (such as an unpaired t-test?), before bothering trying to explain discrepancies away.